# Facebook Messenger website plugin greeting_dialog_display not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, plugins, messenger

The greeting_dialog_display is not working. Or have I misunderstood something..? I've set greeting_dialog_display="hide", but the popup still shows up.

[See live example of issue on codepen][1]

[fork and edit pen][2]

Code example:

```
 <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/fi_FI/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&autoLogAppEvents=1';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- Your customer chat code -->
<div class="fb-customerchat"
  attribution=setup_tool
  page_id="1160695934081727"
greeting_dialog_display="hide">
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

False alarm. The plugin just caches what ever position it's in. So to test you'll need e.g. Chrome incognito with always closing all incognito windows in between.

Comment: Boom! Was pulling my hair out... thanks for posting that!